# Azure Regional VNet Integration and Service Endpoint

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-plans

I try to integrate a web app to a VNET. this is a brand new subscription.

According to : [Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration)

[image]
In the first step I wanted to check if the web app could reach out to VNET. The second step I want to connect the web app to SQL database through a Service Endpoint

I created a VNET with 2 subnets:

1. Jumpbox-subnet
2. integration-subnet
   [image]

integration-subnet setting
[image]

There is service endpoint pointing to the integration-subnet. Also I integrated the app to the VNet, It's delegated the integration subnet.
I tried to connect to VM from App using tcpping 172.16.1.0 (jumpbox VM private address) from app console, but it failed.
I also app cannot connect to the sql database.

What are the missing pieces here, is a DNS server required to make this work?

Update (Resolved):

The question above was the key, It needs away to resolve the name with some sort DNS server.

tcpping default port is 80 and nothing was listening to that port in that box.

Comment: When you do a TCP ping you need to specify a port for the destination. Can you share the TCPping results?

Comment: Yes the Port was missing.

Comment: @Nancy Xiong [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452902/949824) pointed me to the correct location. The issue was DNS setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tool `tcpping` to test for TCP connectivity to a **host and port combination**.

The syntax is: `tcpping.exe hostname [optional: port]`

For example, run `tcpping 172.19.1.10:3389`

[image]

See [troubleshooting app service networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#troubleshooting) for more details.

For more references, Here is an [ARM example](https://github.com/ScottHolden/ARMExamples/blob/master/AppService-VnetNew-Storage/deploy.json) to deploy an app service with VNet integration and enable service endpoint `Microsoft.Storage`.